# Remove non numeric charecters from parsed CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

iam new to ruby.i want to remove non numeric characters from phone number parsed from a CSV file.
Here is the code iam using.

```
require 'csv' 
csv_text = File.read('file.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|                                      
    puts "First Name: #{row['Name']} - HomePhone: #{row['Phone']} -  Zip Code: #{row['Zipcode']}"
end
```

the out put print as Follows

```
   FirstName:Abiel HomePhone:6667-88-76
```

(In CSV file HomePhone contains non numeric characters.)
 I want the out put as `FirstName:Abiel HomePhone:66678876`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
row['Phone'].gsub(/[^0-9]/, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or just `row['Phone'].gsub(/\D/, "")`

where `\d` means a numeric char, and `\D` means anything non-numeric.